# "flutter build apk" is not building all necessary pub packages even those packages are used in my flutter app

Tags: java, android, flutter, kotlin

`flutter build apk` is not building all necessary pub packages even those packages are used in app.

you may ask, how I know some packages are skipped during apk build.

Well, the answer is, when I run the release apk on my phone it shows this error:

```
[ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(177)]
 Unhandled Exception: MissingPluginException(No implementation
 found for method show on channel flutter_svprogresshud)
```

But, in debug mode, everything works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Please follow below steps at the time of release build.

```
1. flutter clean
2. flutter pub get
3. flutter run --release
```

Comment: `run --release` is working but `build apk` is not working. I tried your method before but no change.

Comment: Can you please delete pubspec.lock file and then repeat all the steps?